# Issuing stimulus payment as credit card

Tags: stimulus

The purpose of issuing stimulus money was twofold, the way I see it. First, to help out individuals having difficulty meeting their day to day needs during the pandemic. Second, to prop up the economy as a whole with a infusion of funds. It would seem that any monies saved or invested would not achieve these goals, definitely not to the same degree as if they were spent.
Why then were the payments not issued as a credit card with a specific maximum and with a expiration date of 6 months from date of issue for example. This would ensure the money would be spent rather than saved, and spent sooner rather then later?

Comment: Isn´t there economics comunity on SE now? If yes that could be a beter place for this question.

Comment: How is it different from an EBT card?

Comment: @convert questions of this type aren't really allowed on economics.se, which is about the academic study of economics (not the real world) and comes with rigorous rules on citing sources for example

Answer (score 7):

Because a credit card isn't flexible enough in how it can be spent and would be useless to some. There are places that don't accept credit cards or they charge more because of the credit card fees that are involved. Examples of this are apartments that only accept cash, checks, debit cards or ach.

There is also a need to transfer the money to a bank account in order to use it for various bill pay methods or transferring it to a loan. In general there are many limitations to what can be paid for with a credit card when it comes to things that a stimulus check and what it will be used for.

Answer (score 4):

> This would ensure the money would be spent rather than saved, and spent sooner rather then later?

Money is fungible. This means that all of your income is mixed.

For example, imagine I have $1000/month salary deposited at my bank, and $1000/month expenses, and I get a $500/month "stimulus credit card". If I wanted to save it, I would just use the credit card for half of my expenses and use $500/month from my bank to cover the rest, saving $500/month anyway. It does not matter that the bank account is feed only from my salary, the end result is the same.

What if the stimulus credit card had a $1500/month limit? Then I could spend $1000 in my expenses, and use the $500 on something that I could resell easily or use as to store value(e.g. gold).